# Can we have multiple executors in Spark master local[*] deployment code client

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I have a 1 node Hadoop Cluster, I am submitting a spark job like this

```
spark-submit \
    --class com.compq.scriptRunning \
    --master local[*] \
    --deploy-mode client \
    --num-executors 3 \
    --executor-cores 4 \
    --executor-memory 21g \
    --driver-cores 2 \
    --driver-memory 5g \
    --conf "spark.local.dir=/data/spark_tmp" \
    --conf "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2000" \
    --conf "spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed=true" \
    --conf "spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=200000" \
    --conf "spark.speculation=false" \
    --conf "spark.hadoop.mapreduce.map.speculative=false" \
    --conf "spark.hadoop.mapreduce.reduce.speculative=false" \
    --conf "spark.ui.port=8099" \
    .....
```

Though I define 3 executors, I see only 1 executor in spark UI page running all the time. Can we have multiple executors running in parallel with

```
    --master local[*] \
    --deploy-mode client \
```

Its a on-prem, plain open source hadoop flavor installed in the cluster.

I tried changing master local to local[*] and playing around with deployment modes still, I could see only 1 executor running in spark UI

Comment: Does the computer where you run that command actually have at least 12 cores and 68g of memory to run those 3 executors with those settings? Perhaps you should try lower memory configs, for a start

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your comment, the server I am running in has much more resources, 32 core, 160G ram, but for this job I am trying to use less. But still see only 1 executor. Any reason ?

Comment: That's your Hadoop YARN node? Or your local machine? If you are running YARN, you should be using that as the master instead. According to the deleted answer, running one JVM makes sense, with both driver and executor running in the same, single, JVM for client mode